# "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" 32-bit .run file on 64-bit system

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, execute-command, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install [this](http://developer.choosemuse.com/research-tools/museio) (32-bit) on a 64-bit machine (using Ubuntu 16.04 both as a standalone OS and through WSL) and I keep getting this error, no matter what I do. I solved it a while ago on an Arch installation, but I completely forget how.

```
> file musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run
musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped  

> ./musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run 
bash: ./musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

> sudo ./musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run
./musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run: 1: ./musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Am I missing a 32-bit compatibility library? I've installed quite a few already in several blind attempts to fix this.

EDIT: Here's the output from `ldd` and `uname`

```
> ldd ./musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run
not a dynamic executable

> uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-H99QRQN 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Did you install `lib32z1`?

Comment: @muru I've done everything found there as well.

Comment: Add the output of `ldd ./musesdk-3.4.1-linux-installer.run`, and `uname -a`, please.

Comment: @muru I've done so. I'm currently on my Windows side.

Comment: @Ben the output indicates you don't have libc6:i386 installed. Maybe try on the dual boot instead of on WSL.

Comment: I should point out that WSL is... odd.  It's not exactly a *full* Ubuntu OS, and doesn't provide a lot of the compatibility one would expect with other executable formats.  Just saying.

Comment: @muru Yeah, that solved the problem. I was hoping WSL would work, but this is OK too. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben: Do I understand correctly that you could run the executable successfully in a real Ubuntu installation (i. e. not WSL)? In that case, could you please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: @ThomasWard it is now confirmed that WSL does not support 32 bit binaries: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/13377507-please-enable-wsl-to-run-32-bit-elf-binaries